# Excel Return Multiple Columns Between Dates

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, vlookup

[image]

I am stuck. I have an array, `Data!AX5:AY50`. The column headers are `Release Date(AX5)` and `Campaign(AY5)`. In cell `Tracker!X15`, the user enters `=TODAY()`. In cell `Tracker!Z15` I added `=EOMONTH(X15,-3)+1` which will give me a range. I have a table in `Tracker!W17:Z17` with headers `Date(W17)`, `Campaign(X17)`, `Sold(Y17)`, and `Revenue(Z17)`. In cell `Tracker!W17`, I added `{=IF(ROWS(W$17:W18)>$AB$15,"",INDEX(Data!$AX$5:$AX$49,SMALL(IF(Data!$AX$5:$AX$49<=$X$15,IF(Data!$AX$5:$AX$49>=$Z$15,ROW(Data!$AX$5:$AX$49)-ROW($AX$5)+1)),ROWS(W$17:W18))))}` to pull each unique date and it works perfectly.

My problem is, now I am am trying to use a `VLOOKUP` to return the sum of `campaigns sold(Y17)` and sum of `revenue(Z17)`. The `VLOOKUP` doesn't recognize multiple campaigns released on the same day. Additionally, the `Sold` and `Revenue` figures come from a different table. Is there a way to write a `VLOOKUP` that will account for a 2:1 relationship?

Improperly functioning VLOOKUP for Campaigns:
[image: Improperly functioning VLOOKUP for Campigns]

Comment: I'm thinking maybe a picture would be worth at least 50-70 of these words in trying to comprehend what you are working with and what you are trying to do.

Comment: You're right, I should have added this in the first place, lol

Comment: Cool. That really helps. Can you share with us your non-functioning `vlookup` for `Y17` and `Z17`? My suspicion is that it can be converted to a `countif()` or `sumif()` or `sumproduct()` or something of that nature to do the lookup and addition.

Comment: It wont let me post another link so I cant show you the VLOOKUPs for SOLD and REVENUE.....

Comment: You can just copy and paste the formula. Stick backticks around it and it will appear formatted as `code`.

Comment: `=VLOOKUP(X20,Data!$H$4:$P$193,8,0)` in cell Y20. `=VLOOKUP(X20,Data!$H$4:$P$193,9,0)` in cell Z20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the back and forth. I know that can get tedious.

Instead of a `vlookup` you should go for a `sumif()`. Where `vlookup` will look up the first corresponding value it finds for your search term, a `sumif()` (and `countif()`) will search through a range and sum (or count) based on matches:

For `Y20`:

```
=SumIf($H$4:$H$193, X20, $O$4:$O$193)
```

And 'Z20`:

```
=SumIf($H$4:$H$193, X20, $P$4:$P$193)
```

Those take the form "For range `H4:H193`, where there is a match with `X20`, then take the sum of the corresponding value in `O4:O193`".

Comment: That makes sense. I applied those values and it still isn't quite working. Let me try and mess around with SUMIF and COUNTIF...

Comment: No prob. If there are multiple criteria that you need to test before summing a value, then you can use `SumIfs()` and `Countifs()` which are terribly powerful for aggregating data like this.

Comment: Any ideas on how to get the VLOOKUP in W17 to pull unique values? I think using SUMIFS and COUNTIFS is the way to go for sold and revenue.

Comment: Getting unique values is never fun through a single formula, and it seems like that horrendous array formula is doing the job. I would just stick with it, otherwise you'll be replacing it with another horrendous formula.

Comment: Very true. The massive array formula just works for the unique dates not the campaigns. There are a few different campaigns released on the same date and I'm having trouble getting a formula to return all the unique campaigns. Does that make sense? In the picture, there are 3 Companies That Care but really there should only be 1. There are two other campaigns released on 2/22/2016 that VLOOKUP is ignoring.

Comment: oh! yea... I got ya. I can't think of one off the top of my head, but I feel like index/match/offset and the like might be cobbled together to come up with something. My brain has stopped working for the day :/